# Save Core Data models in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, ios, core-data, xcode4

I want to create a new split view-based iOS project from scratch using the template wizard of Xcode 4.0 (build 4A304a). I ticked the "Use Core Data" checkbox. When I try to save the generated `test.xcdatamodeld` Core Data model, Xcode says **The document "test.xcdatamodel" could not be saved.**

How can I save the file? I already checked the file system for the proper permissions, but they seem alright.

Comment: Haven't seen this one before. If the model valid otherwise?

Comment: @TechZen The generated model has only one entity called "Event" with one "timeStamp" attribute of type Date, which looks fine. The issue navigator displays **No Issues**, so I would assume it is not a validation problem.

Comment: I got nothing. Not sure what would trigger that.

Comment: possibly a stupid question, but you're not out of disk space, are you?

Comment: No, there's enough free disk space, plus I can save models using Xcode 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha - I've been suffering from this problem all day and just found the answer. I ran /Applications/Utilities/Console and tried the save again. This error appeared in the console:

```
AppKit called rmdir("/Users/kris/.TemporaryItems/folders.501/TemporaryItems/
  (A Document Being Saved By Xcode)"), it didn't return 0,
  and errno was set to 66.
```

Though I couldn't see anything obviously wrong with this folder (the permissions & ownership looked normal), removing the whole of ~/.TemporaryItems/ allowed me to save again.

Comment: Not 100% sure why, but it works for me now. Probably because I ran [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/download.php), which cleaned my temporary items (as you suggested).