# Cocoa app error during autosave (errno 66)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a document based app that I've been building and it seems that every now and then when the document makes a temporary save I get the following error:

```
AppKit called rmdir("/private/var/folders/5_/7zdcn8g160g0kbpxhr_fwv0m0000gn/T/TemporaryItems/(A Document Being Saved By MyTestApp)"), it didn't return 0, and errno was set to 66.
```

Now I know that I can resolve the error initially by following this post:
[Save Core Data models in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326835/save-core-data-models-in-xcode-4/6168501#6168501)

However that seems like a temporary solution because the error keeps coming back.  However the error doesn't come back **all** the time, just some times which makes me frustrated.  I'm wondering if anyone could shed light on the source of the problem.

I'm running Mountain Lion 10.8.2 and Xcode 4.5.2.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue with NSDocument. Did you find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it isn't relevant anymore but maybe for someone else - I got the same error, and the issue was that I tried to change read only meta-data field of the UIDocument.

Comment: I have the same issue with NSDocument. What do you mean by "read only meta-data" field?